# How to create object within creation of another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, initialization, mongoid

I am using ruby on rails and mongoid. I have a model called Project and model called Person. I would like to automatically create a new Person object when a new Project is initialized. Is there any way I could insert the code to create a new Person inside the Project model. For example, when I do "Project.create(:name => 'Project 1')", I would like it to automatically create a new Person object. I have already declared a one-to-one relationship between the models.

Do I need to rewrite the create method of the Project model?

Answer (score 0):

In your Project model:

```
after_create :init_first_person

def init_first_person
    self.people.create(name: 'Initialized User')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In you question you originally mentioned

> I would like to automatically create a new Person object when a new Project is initialized.

(which by the way is a very bad idea), but then later on you seems to want to create a Person only when a Project is created.

In this case, my suggestion is to define custom method in the `Project` model that you can call. Don't be afraid of defining new methods. It's way better than using callbacks or override existing default methods.

```
class Project

  def self.create_project_and_user(attributes = {})
    # create the user
    [... ]

    # create the project
    create(attributes)
  end

end
```

Then in your controller you will call `Project.create_project_and_user(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create service object which would look something like that:

```
class CreateProjectService
  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def call
    project = Project.create(params[:project])
    project.person = Person.create
  end
end
```

Then you can use this PORO (Plain Old Ruby Object) in controller by creating it with params from request and calling it. If there would be anything additional to do when creating project then you just add this logic to service.

Really good article to read about patterns used in Rails applications for futher read you can find [here](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/).